# Paging not advancing when using cached query

Tags: caching, cakephp, pagination

My index method does not advance through the result set when it's pulled from the cache; without caching, it works as expected. The page number in
the query params is correctly incremented.

I've reviewed several very old SO questions about this, but they are very out of date with the current CakePHP release (3.8).

```
case ('F'): // Full, paid members
    $query = $this->Members->find('currentFullMembers');

    $cacheKey = md5($this->request->getParam('controller') . 
        $this->request->getParam('action') .  $report) . 'FM';
    $query->cache($cacheKey);

    $this->set('baseYear', $baseYear);
    $this->set('reportTitle', 'Full Members');
    break;
```

Is there something else I need to do for pagination?

Comment: It's unclear what `$report` is in your example, but most likely your `$cacheKey` is static over all pages, ie it doesn't incorporate the page number in any way.

Comment: @ndm $report holds the 'F' used in the case statement. The variable selects which of a number of reports is produced, they differ mostly by the finder method. Yes, you're right, the $cacheKey was not getting updated as I thought. Your comment pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!